# How to execute the path export file in mac?

Tags: macos, mac, path

I have a file with the content:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/PyModel/bin
export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/PyModel/pymodel:$PYTHONPATH
export PYTHONPATH=.:$PYTHONPATH
```

When I try to run this file it opens with the text editor. I want to run this file so that the path is appended in my mac os.

Please help!! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running:

```
source filename
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Place the following on the first line of the file:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Rename the file extension to `.sh`. So if the filename is `file.txt` now it will be called `file.sh`

Don't forget to make it executable:

```
chmod a+x file.sh
```

And finally, run it with `./`:

```
./file.sh
```

Comment: Although this technically **is** a way to "run this file", you do know that this will do nothing effective, ne?  It won't modify the path in the way that the questioner wants.